# Show that the function is continuous which points?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Show that the function is continuous which points.

$$\displaystyle f(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+2i,  & \text{if $z \neq 0$ } \\[2ex]
2i, & \text{if $z=0$ }
\end{cases}$$

Consider $f(0)=2i$ and $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ That is, we consider 
$z$ approach $0$ along the real axis

I have $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=1+2i$

Thus  $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z) \neq f(0)$

Therefore $f(z)$ continuous every point on $\mathbb C$ expect point $(0,0)$

Please check my solution. If it wrong please tell me the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f (i/n) $ to see that $f $ does not have a limit for $z \to 0$.